# Trouble launching AWS environment with django

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I followed the steps line by line in the documentation, but i keep getting this error:

```
Your WSGIPath refers to a file that does not exist.
```

Here is my '.config' file: (except for the appname and the keys)

```
container_commands:
  01_syncdb:
    command: "python manage.py syncdb --noinput"
    leader_only: true

option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python
    option_name: WSGIPath
    value: [myapp]/wsgi.py
  - option_name: DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
    value: [myapp].settings
  - option_name: AWS_SECRET_KEY
    value: XXXX
  - option_name: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
    value: XXXX
```

I googled around and found that someone else had a similar problem and they solved it by editing the 'optionsettings.[myapp]', I don't want to delete something I need, but here is what I have:

```
[aws:autoscaling:asg]
Custom Availability Zones=
MaxSize=1
MinSize=1

[aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration]
EC2KeyName=
InstanceType=t1.micro

[aws:autoscaling:updatepolicy:rollingupdate]
RollingUpdateEnabled=false

[aws:ec2:vpc]
Subnets=
VPCId=

[aws:elasticbeanstalk:application]
Application Healthcheck URL=

[aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment]
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=
PARAM1=
PARAM2=
PARAM3=
PARAM4=
PARAM5=

[aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python]
NumProcesses=1
NumThreads=15
StaticFiles=/static/=static/
WSGIPath=application.py

[aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles]
/static/=static/

[aws:elasticbeanstalk:hostmanager]
LogPublicationControl=false

[aws:elasticbeanstalk:monitoring]
Automatically Terminate Unhealthy Instances=true

[aws:elasticbeanstalk:sns:topics]
Notification Endpoint=
Notification Protocol=email

[aws:rds:dbinstance]
DBDeletionPolicy=Snapshot
DBEngine=mysql
DBInstanceClass=db.t1.micro
DBSnapshotIdentifier=
DBUser=ebroot
```

The user who solved that problem deleted certain lines and then did 'eb start'. I deleted the same lines that the original user said they deleted, but when I 'eb start'ed it I got the same exact problem again.

If anybody can help me out, that would be amazing!

Comment: You need to update `.ebextensions/.config` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20558747/how-to-deploy-structured-flask-app-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk

Comment: Make sure it is committed and pushed to AWS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having this exact problem all day yesterday and I am using ubuntu 13.10.
I also tried deleting the options file under .ebextensions to no avail.
What I believe finally fixed the issue was under 
`~/mysite/requirements.txt` 
I double checked what the values were after I was all set and done doing `eb init` and `eb start` and noticed they were different from what http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Python_django.html mentioned at the beginning of the tutorial.
The file was missing the MySQL line when I checked during the WSGIPath problem, I simply added the line :

```
MySQL-python==1.2.3
```

and then committed all the changes and it worked.

If that doesn't work for you, below are the .config file settings and the directory structure.

My .config file under ~/mysite/.ebextensions is exactly what was in the tutorial, minus the secret key and access key, you need to replace those with your own:

```
container_commands:
  01_syncdb:    
    command: "django-admin.py syncdb --noinput"
    leader_only: true

option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python
    option_name: WSGIPath
    value: mysite/wsgi.py
  - option_name: DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
    value: mysite.settings
  - option_name: AWS_SECRET_KEY
    value: wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY
  - option_name: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
    value: AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE
```

My requirements.txt:

```
Django==1.4.1
MySQL-python==1.2.3
argparse==1.2.1
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

And my tree structure. This starts out in `~/` so if I were to do

- `cd ~/`
- `tree -a mysite`

You should get the following output, including a bunch of directories under .git ( I removed them because there is a lot):

```
mysite
├── .ebextensions
│   └── myapp.config
├── .elasticbeanstalk
│   ├── config
│   └── optionsettings.mysite-env
├── .git
├── .gitignore
├── manage.py
├── mysite
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── settings.pyc
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── wsgi.py
│   └── wsgi.pyc
└── requirements.txt
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, After SOME tinkering, I managed to get it all pieced together. Although my problem had the same symptoms, there was more underlying what was really wrong.